# Internet through wifi just can access google site

Tags: networking, drivers, internet, intel-wireless, 18.10

I just have installed Ubuntu 18.04 and upgraded to Ubuntu 18.10. I install php, mysql, phpmyadmin and remove all these completely. After all, I get a problem where my wifi connection just can access google and I can't access others sites. In other words, I just can searching but I can't access the links appeared. I've predicted following causes but I can't to fix anyone of these:

1. Some configuration have deleted that affect some network
   configurations when I was removing the applications.
2. The wifi driver was corrupted.
3. Others.

How to fix this?